# React Project not compiling after adding TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm getting a strange error as

> ./src/index.js Line 56:15: Parsing error: '>' expected

I followed the official guide by [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) for Adding TypeScript to my existing Create React App project. And after changing just the two .js files(index and App) to .tsx, the project compilation is getting failed.

I uninstalled the global create-react-app by following this [troubleshooting guide](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#troubleshooting)

index.tsx file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <App store={store} persistor={persistor} basename={PUBLIC_URL} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Note: I have changed my index.js file to index.tsx but still getting error for index.js. I guess it's throwing error after compilation to .js

Comment: Add your App.tsx and Index.tsx?

Comment: Please include the content of the relevant line (`./src/index.js Line 56`)

Answer (score 2):

> `/src/index.js Line 56:15: Parsing error: '>' expected`

You are using JSX in a `.js` file. Rename the file to `.jsx` (or even better `.tsx).

## More

You can compare to a TypeScript app by `npx create-react-app example --template typescript`

Comment: I already changed my index.js to index.tsx and App.js to App.tsx

Comment: If you are still getting an error in `src/index.js` even though the file no longer exists, just close and restart the process giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

After a useless struggle of 3 hours I found the root cause of error :)

As I mentioned earlier in the question I removed global create-react-app package to avoid problems but that created the problem. I don't know why but when, **I reinstalled the create-react-app, the problem is resolved!**